# Alter table query in Informix DB

Tags: sql, informix

DBMS: Informix.

I have a table sample_tbl with <s>5</s> 3 fields, that are:

- user_id,
- user_name,
- user_email

Now I want to add the following fields into sample_tbl with one single alter query to add the columns.  The new fields are:

- user_phone_no,
- user_location,
- user_password

I want to add the user_phone_no after the user_id, and I want to add the user_location, user_password after the user_email field, and all with a single query.  Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Why do you care about the columns order? I hope you're not using in your application, queries like `SELECT * FROM sample_tbl...`...

Comment: You said 5 fields but you named only 3.

Comment: The order of the columns matters only because it is homework.  In the old days, the order mattered also when the DBMS was Informix Standard Engine (SE) with C-ISAM for the storage format and the C-ISAM files were also accessed by programs written in C-ISAM (as well as by SE itself).  Once upon 20+ years ago, this was quite common.  Now, it is very rare, mercifully.

Answer (score 13):

According to [IBM online docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls107.htm) Informix v10 allows `ALTER TABLE ADD column BEFORE existing_column`.

So something like this could work (I don't have Informix connectivity on this computer)...

```
ALTER TABLE sample_tbl
ADD user_phone_no varchar(10) BEFORE user_name,
ADD user_location varchar(10),
ADD user_password varchar(10);
```

Comment: Should work fine - well done on the manual bashing.  The notation has been in every version of Informix from 1.10 in 1985 to 11.70 in 2010.

Comment: I wasn't bashing the manual. I just googled the answer, and there was no indication of the version in the question... I just played with Informix from v4 to v9.